# Toggle component with state dependency

Tags: reactjs, toggle, react-props

I'm trying to create a menu to choose the game level and create a board game respectively.

The app crash each time I click the Easy button (or any other, didn't implemented the others yet).

I'm guessing it's something to with the dependency of MemGame component in the rows and columns properties from state, but I can't think of a way to remove this dependency, is there a way to fix this problem?
Or how would you recommend do it differently?

Thanks,

```
state = { 
    rows: 0,
    columns: 0,
    levelMenu: true
 }
render() { 
    return ( 
        <div>
        {this.state.levelMenu?
        <div>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.handleLevelClick(1)}>Easy</Button>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.handleLevelClick(2)}>Medium</Button>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.handleLevelClick(3)}>Hard</Button>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.handleLevelClick(4)}>VeryHard</Button>
        </div>
        :
        <MemGame rows={this.state.rows} columns={this.state.columns} />}
        </div>
     );
}

handleLevelClick(level){
    if(level===1){
        this.setState({rows:2,columns:2});
    }
    .......
 this.toggleMenu()
}

toggleMenu(){
    this.setState({levelMenu: !this.state.levelMenu});
}
```

at the end rows and columns get to a state in other component

```
class Board extends Component {   
state={
    board: this.initialBoard(this.props.rows,this.props.columns),
    numOfOpenCards: 0,
    lastId: "",
    matchCounter:0,
    clickCount: 0, 
    isFinished: false,
    firstClick: false,
    resetRequest: false    
}



 initialBoard(rows,columns){
    let board=[];
    const imageData = this.chooseImages(rows,columns);
    const boardSize = rows*columns;
    for(let index=0;index<boardSize;index++){
        board[index]={
            id: uuid.v4(),
            imgUrl: imageData[index],
            faceUp: false,
            paired: false
        };
    }
    return board;
}
```

Comment: What does the error log show ?

Comment: nothing.
it stuck until chrome asks me if I want to wait or kill page

Comment: I don't know what's inside the `<MemGame>` component but I guess you're calling a function too often. You should have an error like that : **Maximum call stack size exceeded**. Have you bind `this` for the functions `handleLevelClick` and `toggleMenu` in your **constructor** ? Maybe your app doesn't find `this` because you didn't bind it

Comment: If I remove {toggleMenu()} from {handleLevelClick} function it won't crash.
My guess is there is something wrong with changing the rows and columns after it was sent as props.

Comment: What is `Board` component doing here ? Do `MemGame` expect an integer ? Maybe it does expect another type of value. There's a lot of reasons that your app can crash, try to create a fiddle with your issue please, it's really hard to help you.

Comment: MemGame has state that gets rows and columns as props and calls Board component in the render function with rows and columns as props.
it will be pretty complicated to create a fiddle from this project.
Can you maybe refer me to a better logic to create the level selector?